# How to parse info from the log file by certain strings

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner. I have a log file like the below for ~ 1000 cycle loops,

```
"CycleSTART@1
Temp=26C
Fan=3000
CycleSTART@2
Temp=27C
Fan=3200
.
.
.
."
```

My objective is to read the Temp & fan values corresponding to cycle count. Basically I want to put everything in a table.  And I tried with the simple programming

```
string1 = 'CycleSTART@'
string2 = 'Temp'
string3 = 'Fan'

    import pandas as pd
    filepath = "XXX<location of txt file>"
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            line=fp.readline()
            cnt = 1
            while line: 
                cnt += 1
    
        flag = 0
        index = 0
    for line in fp:
            if string1 in line:
                flag = 1
                break
        if flag == 1:
            lword=len(line)
            extracted_string1 = line[11:11+lword]
    for line in fp:
        if string2 in line:
            flag = 2
            break   
    if flag == 2:
        lword=len(line)
        extracted_string2 = line[6:6+lword]

for line in fp:
        if string3 in line:
            flag = 3
            break   
    if flag == 3:
        lword=len(line)
        extracted_string3 = line[5:5+lword]

data = {'cycle': [extracted_string1],
            'temp' : [extracted_string2],
            'Fan' : [extracted_string3],
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['cycle', 'temp', 'Fan']
print (df)
f.close()
```

Tried with this but every time, I get the first cycle value and its not looping to the next cycles.

Comment: I don't think that's the code you're running. Notwithstanding indentation issues, if the file is not empty then you have an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite a little bit and use splits to stay away from regex.

```
import pandas as pd

def add_to_dict(item, key, dic):
    if dic.get(item, False):
        dic[item].append(item)
    else:
        dic[item] = [item]

filepath = "XXX<location of txt file>"
data_container = {}

with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    for indx, line in enumerate(f):

        if indx % 3 == 0:
            value = int(line.split("@")[-1]) # Split on @ and then convert to number
            key = "cycle"
        elif indx % 3 == 1:
            temp = float(temp.split("=")[-1][:-1]) # Split on = and then remove the C to hold the temperature value
            key = "temp"
        elif indx % 3 == 2: 
            fan = int(fan.split("=")[-1]) # Almost same as above, split on = to get the numerical value at the end and convert it to int
            key = "Fan"

        add_to_dict(value, key, data_container)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_container)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. While running, i was getting error   File "Trial_New.py", line 14, in <module>
    cycle, temp, fan = line.split(" ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: Interesting, is one line "CycleSTART@1 Temp=26C Fan=3000" or does the line continue with the other values aswell?

Comment: Yes. it has more than 1000 loops. For each loop, the cycle no (2, 3 etc) and the corresponding Fan & Temp values varies.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that every line in the logfile contains multiple cycles? And on a new row the cycle count starts over?

Comment: CycleSTART@1 
Temp=26C 
Fan=3000 
CycleSTART@2 
Temp=27C 
Fan=3200
CycleSTART@3
Temp=28C 
Fan=3210 <All are in individual line; if i paste here, we see it as a single line>

Comment: Is tehre only a single line of data or is it multiple rows aswell? It's interesting to know if the cycle iteration starts over or not.

Comment: All in individual rows (eg: cycle1 in row1, temp in row2, fan in row3, cycle2 in row4 and so on). its not in single line

Comment: That makes your implementation make more sense, i believe i understand better now. Please check my edited post and if it fits your problem, please give it a upvote and/or the approved solution!